# Show text only if rows in MySQL database equal 1

Tags: php, mysql

How would I get some text to display only if certain rows equal 1. I have a table and there are I have fields labeled 'SEC1', 'SEC2', and 'SEC3'. I can get it to display text for just one equaling to one, but I want something were the fields above have to equal one in order for the text to show.

Any help is appreciated

This is what I am using to get it to work for one:

```
$Completed = ($row["SEC1"] == 1) ? "Completed!" : $row[""]; echo $Completed;
```

Is it possible to modify that to get it to work? I'd be fine with having them added together to equal 3 instead of one.

Comment: Did you skip the "Operators" section of your tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that any of the three fields independently equals "1" then this will do it :

```
if (($row["SEC1"] == 1)||($row["SEC2"] == 1)||($row["SEC3"] == 1)){
//Do what you what
}
```

Or if you mean all three of them combined equal "3" then :

```
if (($row["SEC1"] + $row["SEC2"] + $row["SEC3"]) == 3){
//Do what you what
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am a high school student and still trying to learn all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Why use the ternary operator? Use the 'and' operator to build more complex conditional statements:

```
$Completed = "";

if (($row["SEC1"] == 1) && ($row["SEC2"] == 1) && ($row["SEC3"] == 1)) {
    $Completed = "Completed!";
} 

echo $Completed;
```

There are a lot of different ways you could go about solving this

```
if ($row["SEC1"] + $row["SEC2"] + $row["SEC3"] == 3){
...
}
```